# how to get last-child when I have an unique child + jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, css-selectors

```
<p class="captchaLab">
                    <label id="lbCaptchaCode" class="errorLabel" for="txtCaptchaCode">
                        Recopiez ce code
                        <span>*</span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="Captcha" id="txtCaptchaCode" data-val-captchavalidator-captchaerror="Les caractères indiqués ne sont pas corrects." data-val-captchavalidator-captchaempty="Captcha obligatoire" data-val-captchavalidator="" data-val="true" data-bind="value : CaptchaCode, hasFocus: CaptchaHasFocus">

                    <span id="aCaptchaValidate" style="display: none;" title="" class="invalidLabel">
                        <span class="invalidBble">&nbsp;</span>
                        <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Captcha" class="invalidTxt field-validation-error"><span for="txtCaptchaCode" generated="true" class="">Captcha obligatoire</span></span>
                    </span>
                    <input type="hidden" value="y+p84SkJbs9Z0ZGma8BDGQ==" name="CaptchaProperty.CryptedCaptchaValue" id="hCaptchaCrypted" data-bind="value: captcha">


                </p>
```

Why when I use last-child like this

```
  $('.captchaLab').children('span:last-child')'
```

I haven't the element span?

When I do this:
 `$('.captchaLab').children('span')` I can get the elment.

I need to use last child because sometimes I have one span and sometimes I have more than one span, so I need to get all the times the last element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like

```
$('.captchaLab span:last-child')
```

Or you can try like

```
$('.captchaLab span').last()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should provide you with an answer

http://api.jquery.com/last/